# Lots of generated queries

Tags: database, i18n-l10n, debugging

I enabled devel to **Display query log**

**UPDATE: this problem only happens for logged users**

I found that the **`Frontpage`** generate 900 queries.

```
**67** of them generated by the **Locale** module
```

and

```
**480** of them are of the type: **DrupalDatabaseCache::set**
```

How can I track this problem?

I read that I should disable the i18 module, but I can't do this since it is a multilingual site and I there are other modules that need the i18 module.

This only happens in the **Frontpage** in other pages the queries downs to 300.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem? And what do you have on frontpage that you don't have on other pages?

Comment: Just regular content in the frontpage, some text, images. No blocks, nothing. I think it is a problem because the frontpage takes 10 seconds to fully load.

Comment: @Mołot Don't you think tha 480 queries of the **DrupalDatabaseCache::set** type is too much?

Comment: Simple solution to stop Drupal constantly writing to the cache...switch caching on

Comment: you mean enable caching in `admin/config/development/performance`? I already have it enabled.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that this problem only happens for logged users.

Comment: It would be good to investigate what modules tries to write to cache. Also, I prefer APC and memcached over DB cache. With them it is not a problem at all. But if module writes to cache again and again and again, without reading from it, then it's buggy or "bugously" used, and guilty module should receive a bugreport. **Edit** by default cache is off for logged-in users - if module tries to use it anyway, then it is a kind of bug... or feature? You need [Authcache](https://drupal.org/project/authcache) or sth like it to go around it.

Comment: Do you have l10n_client module enabled?

Comment: @arrubiu no, I used it, but it is disabled now.

Comment: It seems to me like the caching is executed even if I am user 1. Cache shouldn't be executing for logged user...

Comment: Do you have, on frontpage, captcha or something like this? It prevents page from caching.

Comment: no captcha nor similar. What is the code in the buggy module that we are looking for? I mean the code which generate those queries. In this way I can do a text searh in all enabled modules

Comment: @chefnelone `DrupalDatabaseCache::set` is invoked by `cache_set()`, so that's what you're looking for

Comment: Also, it might be worth to search for the cache keys used, if possible.

Comment: @Mołot how do I do that?

Comment: Simplest way? Truncate all cache tables, call frontpage, and then `count(*) group by cid` these tables in your SQL clients. cids are in format like `filter_formats:en`, `theme_registry:runtime:shiny` etc - pretty self-explanatory usually

Comment: Also - repeat the same for one of low-query pages and see the difference. This should reveal what on frontpage abuses your cache so much.

Comment: I found it! It is the theme. I just change the theme and the queries downs to 175.

Comment: Time to file a bugreport. But please post procedure you used for debug as an answer. Unless that's basically something I or Clive told you to do, then you could let one of us to write it, or post it as community wiki to show our shared effort ;)

Comment: @Mołot I´ll will answer the question. But I just changed default theme to Bartik and the problem was gone. Then I don't really know what is the real problem in the theme. Don't know what more can I add to my answer.

Comment: You can answer your question with steps you took to figure out it was a theme. For everyone else with the same problem guilty piece of code will be different, so the steps needed to find it are way more important that actual lines that cause it. After all, real cause will be resolved in issue queue, not here.

Comment: ok, I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in theme. I change to the site Bartik theme and the problem was gone.

I'm using the commerce kickstart distribution if that helps someone. I run into other issues in the past with the frontpage in this distribution. I just remember that and that is why I thought it could be a problem related to the theme. The theme of this distribution has some lines in the preprocess file and that imho may be the source of the problem.

I my situation I will use other theme since I don't need a responsive theme at all.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue then consider tuning Drupal a little. Here's a recent [optimization tips for Drupal I did just a few minutes ago](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102525/long-wait-time-for-website-and-taking-too-much-cpumemory/102539#102539). Then you can run your site with all it's queries and wonderful, useful modules with less pain.